# how to pass input text values to servlet while uploading the file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have two file one is jsp file and second is servlet file .

when i include input text field in jsp file to pass the text to servlet file then as the time running the program that is giving the error msg , why that is happening ?

index.jsp code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>File Upload</h1>
            <form method="post" action="UploadServlet"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="1">
            <tr><td><h3>Input Text at Top of image :</h3> </td><td><input type="text" name="name1" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><h3>Input Text at Bottom of image :</h3> </td><td><input type="text" name="name2" /></td></tr>
            </table><br>
            Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />
            <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

UploadServlet.java servlet file :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,       // 10MB
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)    // 50MB

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet 
{               
    /**
     * Name of the directory where uploaded files will be saved, relative to
     * the web application directory.
     */
    private static final String SAVE_DIR = "uploadFiles";

    /**
     * handles file upload
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        // gets absolute path of the web application
        String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
        String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR+ File.separator +"kala";

        // creates the save directory if it does not exists
        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
        //File dir = new File("E:/Users/al/tmp/000/111/222");
        if(fileSaveDir.exists()){}
        else
        {// create multiple directories at one time
            boolean successful = fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
            if (successful)
            {
                // created the directories successfully
                System.out.println("directories were created successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                // something failed trying to create the directories
                System.out.println("failed trying to create the directories");
            }
        }

        // create multiple directories at one time
        //boolean successful = fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
        System.out.println(savePath);
        //savePath="C:\\Users\\SANJAY GUPTA\\Downloads\\eclipse";
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) 
        {
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            // refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path
            fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }
        String text1 = "";
        String text2 = "";
        text1 = request.getParameter("name1");
        text2 = request.getParameter("name2");
        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!"+"<br>"+savePath);
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(
                            request, response);
    }

    /**
    * Extracts file name from HTTP header content-disposition
    */
    private String extractFileName(Part part) 
    {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String s : items) 
        {
            if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) 
            {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    //UploadServlet u = new UploadServlet();

}
```

how do i get the value passed from jsp to servlet into text1 and text2 String variable ?
error is attached as image [error after including the html code as follow :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFiPc.jpg)

```
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td><h3>Input Text at Top of image :</h3> </td><td><input type="text" name="name1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><h3>Input Text at Bottom of image :</h3> </td><td><input type="text" name="name2" /></td></tr>
    </table>
```

error as a text :

HTTP Status 500 - java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dell\workspaceluna1.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\UploadServlet31\uploadFiles\kala (Access is denied)

```
type Exception report

message java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dell\workspaceluna1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\UploadServlet31\uploadFiles\kala (Access is denied)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dell\workspaceluna1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\UploadServlet31\uploadFiles\kala (Access is denied)
    net.codejava.servlet.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dell\workspaceluna1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\UploadServlet31\uploadFiles\kala (Access is denied)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:372)
    net.codejava.servlet.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.73 logs.
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: error i have given as a image after edit the page , you can see

Comment: Please include errors as text rather than images. Also, it would be good if you could tell exactly at what lines this error is occurring! I would check that you have the right permissions to the indicated save directory.

Comment: now you can see error as a text

Comment: And which line is line 70, where the exception occurs?

Comment: this line is 70 in servlet code  : part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);

Comment: Ok, so the file name does not seem to be extracted from your `extractFileName` method. I tried your method on a fixed String at seems like it is working. Have you looked at what `content-disposition` is exactly at the point where it fails?

Comment: I just thought of one more thing. You are cycling through all the parts, when you really only are interested in one of the parts, the one containing the file. Instead of your loop with `for (Part part : request.getParts())` try to get just the part you want with something like: `Part part = request.getPart("file")`. You will have more than one part in your incoming request and it is quite likely that the first one is actually not the file, but you are still trying to get the `filename` from it.